# como mostrar un fecha en un datatable en asp.net y sql server?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, web, datatables

Buenas Comunidad tengo este problema, tengo un pequeño CRUD de direcciones, todo funciona bien, el problema es que quise mostrar la fecha en una de las columnas del datatable, y no me esta mostrando como deberia, puedo guardar y modificar sin problemas, el problema seria al cargar los datos en el datatable (las fechas)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el codigo del JS para mostrar datos

```
var tabla_persona;
$(document).ready( function () {
    tabla_persona = $('#myTable').DataTable({
        "ajax": {
            "url": "@Url.Action("ListarClientes", "Garantia")",
            "type": "GET",
            "datatype": "json",
            
     

        },
        "columns": [
           { "data": "IDC" },
           { "data": "Nombre" },
           { "data": "Ubicacion" },
           { "data": "Latitud" },
           { "data": "Longitud" },
           //{ "data": "TipoReg" }, 
           {"data" : "avaluo"},
           {
               "data": "idCliente", "render": function (data) {
                   return "<button class='btn btn-primary btn-sm editar' type='button' onclick='abrirModal(" + data + ")'><i class='fas fa-pen'></i></button>" +
                       "<button class='btn btn-danger btn-sm ml-2 eliminar' type='button'  onclick='Eliminar(" + data + ")'><i class='fa fa-trash'></i></button>"
               },
               "orderable": false,
               "searchable": false,
               "width": "150px"
           }
```

este es la clase que uso, uso datetime para las fechas

```
Clase cliente
public class Cliente
    {
        public int idCliente { get; set; }
        public string IDC { get; set; }
        public string Nombre { get; set; }
        public string Ubicacion { get; set; }
        public string Latitud { get; set; }
        public string Longitud { get; set; }
        public string TipoReg { get; set; }
        public string NumGa { get; set; }
        public string TipoPre { get; set; }
        public string CondUso { get; set; }
        public DateTime? avaluo { get; set; }
        public Decimal? valCom { get; set; }
        public Decimal? supTot { get; set; }
        public Decimal? supUsa { get; set; }
        public Decimal? SupAgHab { get; set; }
        public Decimal? SupGaHab { get; set; }
        public string obs { get; set; }
        public string sucursal { get; set; }
        public string region { get; set; }
        public Decimal? USmCua { get; set; }
        public Decimal? Const { get; set; }
        public Decimal? USmConst { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

usa [toLocaleString](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString)

```
let date = Date("/Date(157145760000)/").toLocaleString();

console.log("fechas", date)
```

obtendras este resultado

```
Mon Mar 28 2022 08:42:43 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)
```

o usando `toLocaleDateString`

```
let date = Date("/Date(157145760000)/").toLocaleString();

var fechaCorta = new Date(date).toLocaleDateString();

console.log("fecha corta", fechaCorta)
```

obtienes esto

```
fecha corta 3/28/2022
```

e intenta con esta manera usando tu json

```
 { "data": Date("TipoReg").toLocaleString(); }
```